# Problems with this line transport.call(Soap_Action, envelope); debugger stops here. Android web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, apache-axis, tomcat7

This is my Android main.java I call the webservice from here. But I have some problems, but I dont know which is that fail. I'm using the android debugger but it stops in the line of transpor.call()...

Thanks for all

```
package org.exa.prueba2android;


import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;

import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


import android.widget.TextView;


public class Main extends Activity {

    private static final String accionSoap="http://CartaWS.restaurante.org/showItems";
    private static final String Metodo = "showItems";
    private static final String namespace="http://CartaWS.restaurante.org";
    private static final String url="http://192.168.2.5:8080/CartaWSPrueba/services/CartaWS.CartaWSHttpSoap11Endpoint/";



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        try{

            SoapObject request= new SoapObject(namespace, Metodo);
            //modelo sobre
            SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            sobre.dotNet = true;
            sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(url);
            //LLAMADA 



            //   **HERE IS THE PROBLEM**


             transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre)`;






        //Result
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)sobre.getResponse();
        tv.setText("BEBIDAS: "+result.toString());


        } catch (Exception e){}

    }

}
```

I am using Tomcat7, axis2, java, android, ksoap 2.6.1. Android debugger stops in this line

```
transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre);
```

or maybe the next one

```
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)sobre.getResponse();
```

I'm new here, thank for everything.

Comment: Are you getting an exception? Maybe log that exception somewhere will be useful... it's seldom a good practice to eat exceptions without doing anything.